# Android - find a server in the network

Tags: android, networking, network-programming

I am currently writing a client-server application and I ask myself if there is a better way to find a server in the local network then going trough all the available IP addresses and see if the correct answer is supplied?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You might want to look into UDP broadcasts, where your server announces itself and the phone listens for the broadcasts.

---

[There is an example](http://code.google.com/p/boxeeremote/wiki/AndroidUDP) from the Boxee remote project, quoted below.

### Getting the Broadcast Address

You need to access the wifi manager to get the DHCP info and construct a broadcast address from that:

```
InetAddress getBroadcastAddress() throws IOException {
    WifiManager wifi = mContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    DhcpInfo dhcp = wifi.getDhcpInfo();
    // handle null somehow

    int broadcast = (dhcp.ipAddress & dhcp.netmask) | ~dhcp.netmask;
    byte[] quads = new byte[4];
    for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
      quads[k] = (byte) ((broadcast >> k * 8) & 0xFF);
    return InetAddress.getByAddress(quads);
}
```

### Sending and Receiving UDP Broadcast Packets

Having constructed the broadcast address, things work as normal. The following code would send the string data over broadcast and then wait for a response:

```
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(PORT);
socket.setBroadcast(true);
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data.getBytes(), data.length(),
    getBroadcastAddress(), DISCOVERY_PORT);
socket.send(packet);

byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
socket.receive(packet);
```

---

You could also look into Bonjour/zeroconf, and there is a [Java implementation](http://jmdns.sourceforge.net/) that should work on Android.

Comment: @mark: did it work? [They](http://codeisland.org/2012/udp-multicast-on-android/) say, that not all android devices handle non-unicast traffic correctly. In my case for example `socket.receive(packet);` returned exactly the same packet as it was send. Seems like it didn't even wait for an answer packet from server and just returned the same data.

Comment: I have such UDP discovery in my application, and about 1%-3% of users claims that the server is not found. This is because some routers block UDP broadcast. I am going to additionally use IP scan and/or Bonjour.

Comment: I get `/255.255.255.255` is that the standard?