# Check to see whether root was granted?

Tags: android

I have set up my app to execute the `su` command using this code:

```
try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            altDialog.setTitle("No Root");
            altDialog
                    .setMessage("I am afraid I have been unable to execute the su binary. Please check your root status.");
            altDialog.setCancelable(false);
            altDialog.setButton("Exit App",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Log.e("Android .img Flasher",
                                    "Exiting due to root error");
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
        }
```

This catches if the `su` command doesn't exist (I believe), but not if root was actually granted.

How would I be able to check if root was actually granted?

On a side note, how would I be able to store the output of a command using the `Runtime.getRuntime.exec()` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the code bellow. I've wrote it for generic command use, but it works with `su` command as well. It returns if the command succeed as well as the command output (or error).

```
public static boolean execCmd(String command, ArrayList<String> results){
    Process process;
    try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String [] {"sh", "-c", command});
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } 

    int result;
    try {
        result = process.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    if(result != 0){ //error executing command
        Log.d("execCmd", "result code : " + result);
        String line; 
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream())); 
        try {
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                if(results != null) results.add(line);
                Log.d("execCmd", "Error: " + line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }

    //Command execution is OK
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream())); 

    String line; 
    try {
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            if(results != null) results.add(line);
            Log.d("execCmd", line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

You call it with two arguments:

- `command` - string with command to execute
- `results` - empty ArrayList to return the command output. If null, output is not returned.

To check `su`command you can do the following:

```
//Array list where the output will be returned
ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
//Command to be executed
String command = "su -c ls";
boolean result = execCmd(command,results);
//result returns command success
//results returns command output
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static boolean isRootAvailable(){
            Process p = null;
            try{
               p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"su"});
               writeCommandToConsole(p,"exit 0");
               int result = p.waitFor();
               if(result != 0)
                   throw new Exception("Root check result with exit command " + result);
               return true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Su executable is not available ", e);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Root is unavailable ", e);
            }finally {
                if(p != null)
                    p.destroy();
            }
            return false;
        }
 private static String writeCommandToConsole(Process proc, String command, boolean ignoreError) throws Exception{
            byte[] tmpArray = new byte[1024];
            proc.getOutputStream().write((command + "\n").getBytes());
            proc.getOutputStream().flush();
            int bytesRead = 0;
            if(proc.getErrorStream().available() > 0){
                if((bytesRead = proc.getErrorStream().read(tmpArray)) > 1){
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG,new String(tmpArray,0,bytesRead));
                    if(!ignoreError)
                        throw new Exception(new String(tmpArray,0,bytesRead));
                }
            }
            if(proc.getInputStream().available() > 0){
                bytesRead = proc.getInputStream().read(tmpArray);
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, new String(tmpArray,0,bytesRead));
            }
            return new String(tmpArray);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching for a solution to test if SuperUser Access granted or not, only [Lexip's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66143819/11727388) with Scanner works fine.
To complete his response:

```
boolean isRooted = false;
boolean isRootGranted = false;
try {
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c ls");     // Ask for su and list
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(process.getInputStream()).useDelimiter("\\A");
    if (scanner.hasNext()) isRootGranted = true;
    scanner.close();
    process.waitFor();
    process.getInputStream().close();
    process.destroy();
    isRooted = true;
    if (isRootGranted) Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ROOT granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    else Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ROOT not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch (Exception e) {
    isRooted = false;
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ERROR #SU AUTORISATION\nPHONE NON ROOTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

isRooted = true on a rooted phone, and false if not.
isRootGranted = true if superUser Access is granted, and false if not.
Working everytime you call it.

Regards.