# Discovery System for android and desktop machines

Tags: android, upnp, jini

I have a distributed system that consists of androids and desktop machines and they need to pass data (a simple serialized object) among themselves. I am interested in a jini-like discovery system for android using which androids/desktop machines can discover each other and then transfer data to each other. The distributed system is very dynamic, in the sense, devices come and go quite abruptly and frequently.

I tried to work with [Cling](http://4thline.org/projects/cling/core/) and I could discover my router but could not discover other devices such as android phones. So **I was wondering whether android devices are really UPnP compatible or there might be something wrong with my code.**

I am using the code discussed in the [Cling user manual](http://4thline.org/projects/cling/core/manual/cling-core-manual.html#chapter.Android).

**EDIT:** Posting the code below-

```
public class UpnpBrowserActivity extends ListActivity {

private AndroidUpnpService upnpService;
Registry registry;
private ArrayAdapter<DeviceDisplay> listAdapter;
private BrowseRegistryListener registryListener = new BrowseRegistryListener();

private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        upnpService = (AndroidUpnpService) service;
        registry = upnpService.getRegistry();

        // Refresh the list with all known devices
        listAdapter.clear();
        for (Device device : registry.getDevices()) {               
            registryListener.deviceAdded(registry,device);
        }

        // Getting ready for future device advertisements
        registry.addListener(registryListener);

        // Search asynchronously for all devices
        upnpService.getControlPoint().search();
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        upnpService = null;
    }
};

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upnp_browser);

    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    setListAdapter(listAdapter);

    getApplicationContext().bindService(new Intent(this, AndroidUpnpServiceImpl.class),serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.upnp_browser, menu);
    menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Menu1").setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search);   
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == 0 && upnpService != null) {
        upnpService.getRegistry().removeAllRemoteDevices();
        upnpService.getControlPoint().search();
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (upnpService != null) {
        upnpService.getRegistry().removeListener(registryListener);
    }
    getApplicationContext().unbindService(serviceConnection);
}

class BrowseRegistryListener extends DefaultRegistryListener {

    @Override
    public void remoteDeviceDiscoveryStarted(Registry registry, RemoteDevice device) {
        deviceAdded(device);
    }

    @Override
    public void remoteDeviceDiscoveryFailed(Registry registry, final RemoteDevice device, final Exception ex) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(
                        UpnpBrowserActivity.this,
                        "Discovery failed of '" + device.getDisplayString() + "': " +
                        (ex != null ? ex.toString() : "Couldn't retrieve device/service descriptors"),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show();
            }
        });
        deviceRemoved(device);
    }

    @Override
    public void remoteDeviceAdded(Registry registry, RemoteDevice device) {
        deviceAdded(device);
    }

    @Override
    public void remoteDeviceRemoved(Registry registry, RemoteDevice device) {
        deviceRemoved(device);
    }

    @Override
    public void localDeviceAdded(Registry registry, LocalDevice device) {
        deviceAdded(device);
    }

    @Override
    public void localDeviceRemoved(Registry registry, LocalDevice device) {
        deviceRemoved(device);
    }

    public void deviceAdded(final Device device) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                DeviceDisplay d = new DeviceDisplay(device);
                int position = listAdapter.getPosition(d);
                if (position >= 0) {
                    // Device already in the list, re-set new value at same position
                    listAdapter.remove(d);
                    listAdapter.insert(d, position);
                } else {
                    listAdapter.add(d);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void deviceRemoved(final Device device) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                listAdapter.remove(new DeviceDisplay(device));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

I also read [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198669/any-way-to-discover-android-devices-on-your-network) but if android devices cannot be discovered with Cling or another similar library, I would prefer to write a small discovery system using TCP/IP sockets.

Kindly guide me if I am missing or misunderstanding something. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Android devices are capable of running a UPnP stack.  That doesn't mean that all Android devices publish UPnP devices however.  Are you trying to detect arbitrary Android kit using UPnP?  Or do you want to add your own software to certain Android devices which publishes UPnP devices from them?  I don't think the former will work; the latter should be pretty easy.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I want to write software that would publish other android devices and desktop machines (I assume this is what a registry does) so that these devices/machines can consume and share the data between each other. I think this is similar to the second part of your comment. Could you please tell me how do I achieve this?

Comment: If you have tried to use Cling to create a UPnP device on an Android phone, it'd be good if you could post a question that includes your code.

Comment: edited my question with the code

Comment: I'm not familiar with cling but that code does not seem to create and advertize a device, it just lists the upnp devices on the network. What @simonc is saying is that the devices you want to discover _must_ be running code that actually advertizes a upnp device/service -- stock android has nothing like that running by default. In other words you can't discover a device that is just a random android phone.

Comment: Could anybody please guide me how do I announce presence of android devices on the network?

Comment: @aboli81, now i'm facing this problem. Did you got the solution for it?