# How to get the connected clients information from a network in Android?

Tags: android, networking, mac-address

Currently I am making an app which requires the MAC addresses of the connected clients on a network.(The app is also connected as a client).
Is it possible to get the informations such as I.P. and MAC Addresses of the connected clients on a network?

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198669/any-way-to-discover-android-devices-on-your-network

Comment: @DanielNugent really a helpful post!
Have to study it thoroughly!
need some improvisations here!
thanks btw...!!!