# How to connect my Android app to local server using domain?

Tags: android, local

I have an android app that work locally in a gym . It connects to local server through the IP. The problem is, local server get IP from DHCP access point and sometimes the IP changes, causing the App unable to connect to the server.

I use IIS as web server . How do i fix this issue? If i setup IP manually, it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you configure the DHCP server to always give the same IP to your server?

Comment: ... Or use a static IP address ...

Comment: check my answer, it should work out for your problem

Answer (score 0):

This is a classical network discovery problem. You can use udp datapackets to identify the server.

client =  android app, server = your local server
Server Implementation

1. Open a socket on the server that listens to the UDP requests. (I’ve chosen 8888)
2. Make a loop that handles the UDP requests and responses
3. Inside the loop, check the received UPD packet to see if it’s valid
4. Still inside the loop, send a response to the IP and Port of the received packet

Client implementation

1. Open a socket on a random port.
2. Try to broadcast to the default broadcast address (255.255.255.255)
3. Loop over all the computer’s network interfaces and get their broadcast addresses
4. Send the UDP packet inside the loop to the interface’s broadcast address
5. Wait for a reply
6. When we have a reply, check to see if the package is valid
7. When it’s valid, get the package’s sender IP address; this is the server’s IP address
8. CLOSE the socket! We don’t want to leave open random ports on someone else’s computer

http://michieldemey.be/blog/network-discovery-using-udp-broadcast/

[Android - find a server in the network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464207/android-find-a-server-in-the-network)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) to reach your server using a domain name that the DDNS service you choose will create, and the DDNS system will automatically map it to the DHCP IP of your server.
Usually DDNS is free for some times and then you have to pay, other DDNS services are free forever but need you to give a hit to your personal service account for not being calcelled.

With DDNS all you have to do is choose from existing DDNS services (http://dyndns.it/, http://www.noip.com/free, ecc ecc) and follow the procedure in the respective website.

Be sure to know if the DDNS service is able to listen at the correct port (it may not be 80 if you're not using restful service)