# Multicast & Instant Apps

Tags: java, android, permissions, multicast, android-instant-apps

Usually I can use a [MulticastSocket](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/MulticastSocket) or a [network service discovery](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd) to find a server over a Wi-Fi network

```
try (MulticastSocket multicastSocket = new MulticastSocket(Network.DISCOVERY_PORT)) {
    multicastSocket.setNetworkInterface(Network.getWifiInterface());
    multicastSocket.setSoTimeout((int) (3 * DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS));
    multicastSocket.joinGroup(InetAddress.getByName(Network.DISCOVERY_IP));
    ...
}
```

It works fine, however I could not use these methods inside an [Instant App](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7240211?hl=en) module, because it needs the **ACCESS_WIFI_STATE** permission that is not allowed.

Knowing that the instant apps allow the **ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE** and **INTERNET** permission, is there any way to find a local server IP, avoiding this error?

```
java.net.BindException: bind failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

The [available permissions](https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/getting-started/instant-enabled-app-bundle#configure-permissions) are :

> ```
> ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
> ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
> ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
> BILLING – Deprecated as of Play Billing Library 1.0.
> CAMERA
> INSTANT_APP_FOREGROUND_SERVICE – Only in Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher.
> INTERNET
> READ_PHONE_NUMBERS – Only in Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher.
> RECORD_AUDIO
> VIBRATE
> WAKE_LOCK
> ```

Comment: Have you tried some other methods like from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464207/android-find-a-server-in-the-network? However, if they all use a disallowed permission, then it will not be possible.

Comment: Thank you for you help. Unfortunately, these methods do not work with IPv6 addresses.